# Calling a service on Spock gets null object

Tags: java, spring-boot, groovy, spock

Im trying to perform test under the spock framework with the following structure

```
class UserServiceSpec extends Specification{

   ModelMapper modelMapper = Stub(ModelMapper.class)

   UserRepository userRepository=Mock(UserRepository.class)

   UserService userService

   def setup(){
       userService= new UserServiceImpl(userRepository,modelMapper)
   }
   def "find user by email"(){
      given: "Creates a constant with an existing email"
          def constant ="juan@rodriguez.com"
      when: "Calling the method findUserByEmail"
          def response= userService.findUserByEmail(constant)
      then:"Comparing the response result with the constant"
        
         response.getEmail()==constant
   }
}
```

However when i try to get the value of response.getEmail(), the result is a null object and it should get the same parameter as "constant", the error is:

```
Cannot invoke method getEmail() on null object
```

The code structure for UserService and the implementation is:

```
 public interface UserService {

     UserModel findUserByEmail(String email);
 }
```

The UserService implementation is :

```
@Service
@Qualifier("userDetailsService")
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService, UserDetailsService {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    private final ModelMapper modelMapper;

    public UserServiceImpl(UserRepository userRepository,ModelMapper modelMapper){
       this.userRepository= userRepository;
       this.modelMapper= modelMapper;
    }

}
```

However, if i call the Service from the controller (spring project) with the same method i get an object with it's parameter. How is it possible to fix this spock test?

- I tried "@Autowired" for the service instead of initializing as a UserServiceImpl but it does not work.
- I tried without mocking the mapper and the repository and still getting the same null object.

Comment: Note that you don't need your `setup` method; you can just make the assignment inline.

Comment: @alex, it is not super helpful to ask why `findUserByEmail(String)` returns `null`, but omitting the method definition from your sample code. In this case, chrylis made an educated guess that the method internally uses UserRepository, and probably he is right and answered your question correctly. Nevertheless, it is a speculative answer because you are hiding information here. Please update your question, ideally turning it into an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), then you will also get a more precise answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't specify any interactions with the mock `UserRepository`, so Spock returns `null` from any method call you make on it. Presuming your repository is an ordinary one, say something like this:

```
then:
userRepository.findByEmail(constant) >> { c -> new UserEntity(email: c, ...) }
constant == response.email // expected value comes first, and you can use Groovy property syntax
```

Comment: the repository was a normal one, thanks for ur help :)